# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-1-"

Tags: java

I want to send sms  which contain arabic message using java API

mobily provider offers a java api to send sms

I used this code java :

```
public void sendMessage(String userName,String password,String sender,String message,String numbers){
            String para ="mobile=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&numbers=" + numbers+ "&sender=" + sender + "&msg=" + convertUnicode(message) + "&applicationType=24";
            sendURL("http://www.mobily.ws/api/msgSend.php",para,1);
            System.out.println(getMessage());
    }



    public static String convertUnicode(String a) {
        int bufSize = 16;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
        String s = null;
        try {
            buffer=a.getBytes();
            s = bytesToHex(buffer,0,buffer.length);
            System.out.println("Hex: "+s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return s;
    }
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        for (int j=0; j<len; j++)
            buf.append(byteToHex(b[off+j]));
            return buf.toString();
    }
    public static String byteToHex(byte b) {
        char[] a = { hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f] };
        return forDigits(new String(a));
    }
    public static String forDigits(String val){
        switch (val.length() ){
            case 1:return "000"+val;
            case 2:return "00"+val;
            case 3:return "0"+val;
            case 4:return ""+val;
            default:return val;
        }
    }


public void sendURL(String URL,String parameters,int operationNumber){
        try {
            URL url;
            URLConnection urlConnection;
            DataOutputStream outStream;
            // Create connection
            url = new URL(URL);
            urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            ((HttpURLConnection)urlConnection).setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+ parameters.length());
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-agent","Mozilla/4.0");
            // Create I/O streams
            outStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            // Send request
            outStream.writeBytes(parameters);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            // Get Response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            // - For debugging purposes only!
            String buffer;
            while((buffer = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                try{
                    selectedMessage(Integer.parseInt(buffer),operationNumber);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    balance=buffer;
                }
            }
            // Close I/O streams
            rd.close();
            outStream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception cought:\n"+ ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

the problem is that the buffer value is "-1-"

This value is filled in this line :

**buffer = rd.readLine()**

so I always find myself in this exception

> ```
> }catch(Exception ex){
>                   balance=buffer;
>               }
> ```

the parameters sent in the **sendMessage** method:

sender :شارع علي

message :وجهت إلى

numbers : 00966569114455

**Updated :**

I arrived to send a **message in English**

sender  :  test

message : test

in this line   `while((buffer = rd.readLine()) != null) {`

the value of buffer equal to  **1**

**the problem is just for sending messages in Arabic**

I try to change my code without success with :

```
   while((buffer = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          
                try{
                      buffer = buffer.replaceAll("(-?[0-9]+)([^0-9]*)?","$1");
                    buffer=buffer.replace("-", "");
                    selectedMessage(Integer.parseInt(buffer),operationNumber);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    balance=buffer;
                }
```

also in this line in **sendURL** method:

```
 urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
```

and in this line in **convertUnicode** method :

```
buffer=a.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

this is my function which return the final message :

```
public void selectedMessage(int value,int operationNumber){
    switch(operationNumber){
        case 1:switch(value){
                    case 1:msg= "SUCCESS";break;
                    case 2:msg="ERROR";break;
                    
               }break;
    
        }
}
```

with my modified code I force the buffer value to be equal to 1

in **sendURL method** the value of **parameters**  is  :

```
mobile=966556541236&password=123654&numbers=966569114455&sender=شارع علي&msg=00D800A700D9008400D9008500D800B900D800A700D9008500D9008400D800A9002000D800B100D9008200D9008500D9008800D800AC00D9008700D800AA002000D800A500D9008400D90089002000D9008600D800B800D800A700D90085002000D9008400D9008400D800AA00D800AF00D800B100D9008A00D800A8&applicationType=24
```

Comment: The title says the value is "-1-" and the description says it's "-1". Which is it?

Comment: sorry,  the buffer value is "-1-"

Comment: Since you're obviously dealing with non-ASCII strings, can I recommend that you specify explicit character sets for methods like `String.getBytes()`, i.e. `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, rather than relying on the JVM default.

Comment: So *why* do you get "-1-" back as the first line? What is the value expected to be? Could this be mishandling the response data (ie. invalid parsing or not handling an error response)?

Comment: the buffer value should be 1

Comment: Well, it isn't. Fix the assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing a RegEx replaceAll on the input first, to filter the input.

#### Example:

```
buffer = rd.readLine().replaceAll("(-?[0-9]+)([^0-9]*)","$1");
```

This will convert input like so:

```
-1-    ->    -1
-1     ->    -1
 1-    ->     1
```

Comment: I have updated my code ,I force the buffer value to be equal to 1 but the the SMS is not sent,

Comment: @franco "Forcing the buffer" is *not* necessarily "getting a response of 1". Does "-1-" indicate some error? If you are going to force the buffer/result arbitrarily, you might as well just ignore it.

Comment: @franco A "-XYZ" response is an error code; why you are getting "-1-" instead of one of the shown numbers, I don't know. But on an error the SMS will not be sent. Ref http://www.mobilybsms.ws/mobilybsmsAPI.pdf

Comment: @franco http://demo-tag.net/sms/api-php3/API%20Details.pdf has "-1" meaning "Not connected to database", but doesn't explain why/if there should be a trailing dash. (The mobility site really sucks on showing what the *actual* responses should be.)